# How to use separate custom json serializers for parent and child classes?

Tags: java, json, serialization, fasterxml

In the below example, I have a primary class - A and its subclass - B:

```
public class A
{
   public final String primaryKey;

   A(String primaryKey)
   {
        this.primaryKey = primaryKey;
   }
}

public class B extends A
{
   public final String secondaryKey;

   B(String primaryKey, String secondaryKey)
   {
        super(primaryKey);
        this.secondaryKey = secondaryKey;
   }
}
```

Also I have custom serializer:

```
public class ASerializer extends StdSerializer<A> {
    public ASerializer(Class<A> t)
         super(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(A value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) {
        try {
            jgen.writeStartObject();
            jgen.writeFieldName("base");
            jgen.writeStartObject();
            jgen.writeStringField("CustomKeyA", value.primaryKey);
            jgen.writeEndObject();
            jgen.writeEndObject();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

So, the following code uses the custom serializer for json serialization:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule testModule = new SimpleModule("testModule", Version.unknownVersion());
testModule.addSerializer(A.class, new ASerializer(A.class));
result = mapper.writeValueAsString(new B("A", "B"));
System.out.println(result);
```

Actual output:

```
{
    "base" : {
         "CustomKeyA":"A"
    }
}
```

Expexted output:

```
{
    "base" : {
         "CustomKeyA":"A"
    },
    "secondaryKey":"B"
}
```

So, how can I serialize a super class members in custom way and all other child class members in standard way? Thanks.

UPD: Corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your use case is limited to only defining a specific name for a field of class `A`, then you *do not need* to implement and register a custom serializer. The desired output is achievable by adding

```
@JsonProperty("CustomKeyA")
public final String primaryKey;
```

Both `primaryKey` and `secondaryKey` properties will be processed by Jackson for class `B` and included into the output as `CustomKeyA` and `secondaryKey` respectively.

Using a custom serializer gives total control over the elements to output, bypassing the default serialization mechanism: it means that the properties will have to be handled "manually", which can easily become complicated for class hierarchies.

*Update*

If you are not allowed to modify the original classes `A` or `B`, there still can be a work-around using the serializer.

The main difficulty of the approach is that the serializer for the parent class `A` does not know much about the properties of objects that it might receive that inherit from `A`. It would be very hard to check for particular type, cast and output the corresponding fields. It will be especially hellish to maintain.

The idea of the solution that I can suggest is: retrieve the properties of the object as a `Map` using Jackson's mechanics (so that all the outputtable properties would be there) and replace the one of the parent class with appropriate key. Then output the map into JSON.

This can be implemented as follows:

```
public class ASerializer extends StdSerializer<A> {

  // we'll use this mapper to convert the object into a Map
  private static final ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

  // contains the list of property names that belong to parent class only
  private static final Set<String> BASE_PROPERTIES = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("primaryKey"));

  public ASerializer() {
    this(A.class);
  }

  public ASerializer(Class<A> t) {
    super(t);
  }

  private void serializeBaseProperties(A value, JsonGenerator jgen) throws IOException {
    // create a Map of base properties and their values to serialize under "base"
    final Map<String, Object> baseProperties = new HashMap<>();
    baseProperties.put("CustomKeyA", value.primaryKey);
    // output the map
    jgen.writeFieldName("base");
    jgen.writeObject(baseProperties);
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  private void serializeOwnProperties(A value, JsonGenerator jgen) {
    ((Map<String, Object>) MAPPER.convertValue(value, Map.class)) // grab all serializable properties
      .entrySet().stream()
      .filter(entry -> !BASE_PROPERTIES.contains(entry.getKey())) // filter out the ones from base class
      .forEach(property -> writeProperty(property, jgen)); // output own properties to JSON
  }

  @Override
  public void serialize(A value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
    jgen.writeStartObject();
    serializeBaseProperties(value, jgen);
    serializeOwnProperties(value, jgen);
    jgen.writeEndObject();
  }

  private void writeProperty(Map.Entry<String, Object> property, JsonGenerator jgen) {
    try {
      jgen.writeFieldName(property.getKey());
      jgen.writeObject(property.getValue());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
    }
  }

}
```

There might be another approach, by creating a hierarchy of serializers, in parallel with the target classes hierarchy. That will also work, but once again, that creates redundancies and makes it harder to maintain.

*End-of-update*

Comment: Thanks, yes it will work, but I cannot edit classes, they are generated. I have a lot of classes inherited from a base class and I need to serialize the base class members in custom way.

Comment: Ok, @morbili, I've just updated my answer with another approach, taking into account that `A` and `B` cannot be changed.

Comment: Thanks, @Antot, it is a good approach and it will work in case if I need only rename properties names, but I need custom processing for base class members and standard processing for other class members.
I have updated serializer, actual and expected, now it should look more precisely.

Comment: Hi, @Antot, could you please tell more in detail about creating a hierarchy of serializers or give some links to that, thanks.

Comment: Well, after a few thoughts I conclude that it would be too hackish to play with a hierarchy of serializers. It's not so obvious to mix partial custom serializing with standard mechanics for same object and keep the genericity for all other implementors without becoming too verbose :)
However, I've updated once again the code in the answer, to make it more readable. I hope that helps.

Comment: Well, thanks a lot for your help, I think the last solution is what I will try to use right now, at least it should work with one-level classes inheritance A <- B.